# How to align texts with different width using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a section which contain text with different width.

```css
.demo h1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  color: #707070;
  text-align: justify;
}

.demo p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  color: #707070;
}

.demo {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>Dene do kontaktu</h1>
  <p>Skontaktuj się</p>
  <p>Tel: 500500500</p>
  <p>Email: kontakt@kontakt.pl</p>
</div>
```

Here is visual of what is expected:

[image]

Comment: So all you want is to center the text?

Comment: connexo I want as image shows, i tried centering the text but all of them are equal , am not getting what is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center text, use `text-align: center`, not `justify`. I also optimized your CSS a little.

```css
.demo {
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: center;
}

.demo h1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.demo .tel {
  color: #00bb11;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>Dene do kontaktu</h1>
  <p>Skontaktuj się</p>
  <p>Tel: <span class="tel">500500500</span></p>
  <p>Email: kontakt@kontakt.pl</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, all of you guys , your solution works, but the answer must be accepted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center your text you use the `text-align: center` property.

Remove text align from your other css properties and edit demo

```
.demo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xhe5mgc1/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `text-align: center;`

Comment: No that  does not work, some one got nice solution @connexo joseph

Answer (score 0):

All you need it text-align: center on the outer div and remove justify on the h1.

```
.demo h1{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    color: #707070;
}

.demo p{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    color: #707070;
}

.demo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change the value of "text-align" in the class .demo to center

```css
.demo h1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  color: #707070;
}

.demo p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  color: #707070;
}

.demo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>Dene do kontaktu</h1>
  <p>Skontaktuj się</p>
  <p>Tel: 500500500</p>
  <p>Email: kontakt@kontakt.pl</p>
</div>
```